# How can I create a network drive that works over the Internet?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I have a company that needs to share files between 2 locations. Both locations are using Mac computers only. How do I create something that is equivalent to a network drive that can be accessed via the Internet from both locations? I don't want the users to have to copy the files to their own computer and then re-upload them. I would like the files to be directly accessed from a central point that allows concurrent access to files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest dropbox.  Install the software to both machines.  It installs a "mapped drive"  Set up the account with dropbox, and access the share with the same account, or set up two accounts and set sharing permissions to allow both users to access the files.  That should serve your need!

Answer (score 1):

If you need more space than Dropox provides and have a dedicated server, you can use lsyncd (http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) - not as easy as Dropbox, but doesn't have its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dropbox or a similar service